# Only have specific JSON attributes in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs

I can get an array of JSON objects

```
[
{
Id: "1",
StartNo: "1",
ChipNo: "0",
CategoryId: "0",
Wave: "0",
Club: "",
FirstName: "Lotta",
LastName: "Svenström",
FullName: "Lotta Svenström",
ZipCode: "24231"
},
{...}
]
```

I want to create a new data structure that only contains the StartNo and FullName. How do I achieve this?

I have tried:

```
$scope.runners = [];

for(var i = 0; i<data.length; i++){
    $scope.runners[i].StartNo = data[i].StartNo;
    $scope.runners[i].Fullname = data[i].Fullname;
}
```

But that doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a new object using only these two properties:

```
for (var i = 0; i < $scope.runners.length; i++){
    $scope.runners[i] = {
        StartNo: data[i].StartNo,
        Fullname: data[i].Fullname
    }
}
```

Or alternatively, if you need to keep references, delete all other properties from the object:

```
for (var i = 0; i < $scope.runners.length; i++){
    for (var k in $scope.runners[i]) {
        if ($scope.runners[i].hasOwnProperty(k) && k !== 'StartNo' && k !== 'Fullname') {
            delete($scope.runners[i][k]);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the `map`-function of `Array`:

```
var data = [...your JSON objects...];

$scope.runners = data.map(function(runner) {
    return {
        StartNo: runner.StartNo,
        Fullname: runner.Fullname
    };
});
```

Comment: Note about compatibility: `map` does not work in IE8 and below.

Answer (score 1):

you can use native `map` like bellow

```
var $scope.runners = data.map(function(obj){
                     return {StartNo:obj.StartNo,FullName:obj.FullName};
                     });
```

Answer (score 1):

try this code

```
    var data=[
{
Id: "1",
StartNo: "1",
ChipNo: "0",
CategoryId: "0",
Wave: "0",
Club: "",
FirstName: "Lotta",
LastName: "Svenström",
FullName: "Lotta Svenström",
ZipCode: "24231"
}
];

var runners =[];


for(var i = 0; i<data.length; i++){
runners[i]={};
   runners[i].StartNo = data[i].StartNo;
    runners[i].Fullname = data[i].Fullname;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 $scope.runners=[];
$scope.sampleRunner = [
    {
        Id: "1",
        StartNo: "1",
        ChipNo: "0",
        CategoryId: "0",
        Wave: "0",
        Club: "",
        FirstName: "Lotta",
        LastName: "Svenström",
        FullName: "Lotta Svenström",
        ZipCode: "24231"
    },
    {
        Id: "1",
        StartNo: "2",
        ChipNo: "0",
        CategoryId: "0",
        Wave: "0",
        Club: "",
        FirstName: "Lotta",
        LastName: "Svenström",
        FullName: "Velu",
        ZipCode: "24231"
    },];

    angular.forEach($scope.sampleRunner, function (data) {
            $scope.runners.push({ StartNo: data.StartNo, FullName: data.FullName });
        });
```